# О(,) как больно душе, как мне хочется плакать! Перестаньте рыдать надо мной, журавли!

Tags: вводные-слова, частица, междометие

*О, как больно душе, как мне хочется плакать!

Перестаньте рыдать надо мной, журавли!..*

Смущает запятая после "О".

Это слова из оригинального текста "Журавлей" ("Здесь под небом чужим") Алексея Жемчужникова. Во всех вариациях пунктуация аналогичная, но это мне сейчас не очень интересно, возможно просто инерция, вызванная первоисточником.

Хочется понять, зачем эту запятую поставил автор.

Кстати, в первой строчке - аналогичное сомнение.

*Сквозь вечерний туман мне, **под небом стемневшим**,

Слышен крик журавлей всё ясней и ясней…*

Обособление "под небом стемневшим" в принципе-то объяснить можно, но как-то не по ситуации оно тут, нет?! Наоборот, хочется чтобы ни взгляд, ни голос об эти запятые не спотыкались.

Есть разные источники, но все эти запятые довольно регулярно присутствуют, что позволяет думать, что на то воля автора. Но чем он-то руководствовался?!

**UPD** 
Ответы типа

> Междометие О может не отделяться от обращения, но здесь никакого
>   обращения нет. Поэтому отделяем.

всерьез не рассматриваю. Во-первых, здесь вернее всего не междометие, а усилительная частица, во-вторых, грубо нарушен силлогизм.

Не помню точно, как это звучит у Аристотеля, поэтому своими словами. 
*Англичане могут быть рыжими. Если кто-то не рыжий, это не значит, что он не англичанин.*

Ну и вот бесспорный фактический пример.

> "О сколько нам открытий чудных"

(С)АСП

> О времена! О нравы!

Цицерон(?)

А здесь?!

О шея лебедя!
О грудь!
О барабан и эти палочки -
                   трагедии знаменье!

(Чапек)

Ну да, все это назывные предложения, но никак не обращения.

Answer (score 1):

А как Вы определили, что это частица? Розенталь объясняет:

> 3. Следует различать междометия и одинаково звучащие частицы: после междометий запятая ставится, после частиц — нет. Ср.: О, это была бы
>      райская жизнь!.. (Г.) — О поле, поле! Кто тебя усеял мёртвыми костями?
>      (П.)
>
>    Примечание. При разграничении подобных случаев учитывается значение и
>      употребление частиц: 1) частица о употребляется при риторическом
>      обращении и запятой не отделяется: О вы, кому в удел судьбою дан
>      высокий сан! (Кр.); так же перед словами да и нет: О да, конечно; О
>      нет, ни в коем случае;

Заметили, что частица О может стоять перед риторическим обращением и перед словами ДА и НЕТ?  В разговорном стиле может усиливать КАК (вместо ВОТ КАК! -
 О КАК!), здесь "о как" -  междометие с частицей.  Все остальные случаи употребления О - междометия, а они отделяются запятой или восклицательным знаком. Так что автор руководствовался  правилами. А насчёт Пушкина, запятой у него нет только в черновике, в черновиках у всех много несоответствий правилам, все ошибки исправляются потом, при подготовке к печати. При жизни Пушкина стихотворение не было напечатано, в печатных изданиях запятая есть. У меня в трёх изданиях есть - проверяла. На сайтах по-разному, это не показатель, на более или менее серьёзных тоже есть:

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/1880/%D0%9E

http://poetpushkin.ru/stihi/filosofskaya-lirika/o-skolko-nam-otkrytij-chudnyh-gotovyat-prosveshhenya-duh.html

http://1slovar.ru/wingwords/1826

https://znanija.com/task/23805177

*Сквозь вечерний туман мне, под небом стемневшим,*

*Слышен крик журавлей всё ясней и ясней…*

Вы сами сказали, что объяснить можно: пояснительный оборот. Захотелось автору выделить **под небом стемневшим** - он выделил. Имеет право, на то он и автор. Может, это оправдано именно ситуацией: осень, вечер, туман, стемнело, журавлей не видно, только их крик - тоска... Днём на первом месте были бы сами птицы, их клин, а "под небом стемневшим" - их крик.

Comment: *Заметили, что частица О может стоять перед риторическим обращением и перед словами ДА и НЕТ?* Людмила, вы - подобно многим филологам и гуманитариям вообще и вслед за Niemand'ом (не к носи будь помянут) путаесь в элементарном силлогизме. Вы можете утверждать, что частица может стоять **ТОЛЬКО** там  (перед  обращением и да/нет)? Я - нет. Во всяком случае из Розенталя и проч. этого не следует. Что касается черновиков Пушкина... я уточню. Мне казалось, что я цитировал по вполне авторитетному источнику, но по памяти (ибо делал это неоднократно).

Comment: *Имеет право, на то он и автор.* Да кто бы возражал. Хочется понять, чем он думал... Это ж стихи все-таки, тут эмоциональное восприятие подчас важнее правописания.

Comment: Так про эмоции и речь, "О" здесь эмоционально, потому и междометие, я, например, не могу произнести без паузы, а Валгина говорит: "Усилительные частицы не имеют ударения, в произношении они сливаются со следующими словами, тогда как междометия всегда ударны и потому самостоятельно оформлены. О любимые сердцу обманы (Забол.). – О, концерт большой будет,  – обронил кто-то из мужиков (Крут.)." Если о - частица, то она сольётся с "как"и усилит его: О как больно душе = вот как больно = очень больно, а у автора сначала эмоции- О, а потом их объяснение.

Comment: *"О" здесь эмоционально, потому и междометие, я, например, не могу произнести без паузы,* - Ой... А я не могу с паузой. Вот видите, насколько опасно полагаться самоочевидность подобных вещей. Если бы я понимад это как вы, вопроса бы и не было. Кстати, Пушкина я посмотрел. В двух доступных мне академических изданий запятой нету. Но это я чуть позже все напишу. Если силы будут. Пока готовлю еще примеры - в тексте вопроса будут.